# Is there any way we can include the source of a managed package inside a customer specific managed package?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp

I am really new to the packaging process for creating managed package and looking for a help from the experts,

We do have a use-case where we need to include the source of a managed package inside a customer specific managed package,

Let's say we have a core managed package called Package A (Repo A) which contains the core functionalities of our product and have another customer specific package called Package B (Repo B) where we use some of the classes of the Package A.

The question here is, do we have a way to package both the sources into one package when creating a package for the Customer? Which means without giving a customer with 2 different packages with the installation order, we need to bundle/ build a package with the Customer Specific implementation  source + the core functionalities source.

Is this possible in the 2GP packaging model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to inject an existing managed package to be a part of another managed package. Obviously, you could combine the source codes of both packages and create a new package, but that would really not be preferable or even worthy of being considered an OK approach. Instead of trying to combine 2 packages into a single managed package,

- Retain 2 different managed packages so you can leverage the benefits of modular development approach and keep the code maintenance effort optimal in the future.
- Define the dependency over one or more packages. This will also enable you to be able to create patch versions for each of these packages and be able have a mix of different version dependencies among these packages for various customers in the future. Or, you can be able to opt to have one package as Unlocked, if needed.

You can define `dependencies` in the *sfdx-project.json* file (under `packageDirectories`). Sample snippet can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_extract_dependency_info.htm) & more details about package dependency can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_about_dependencies.htm).

If the customer tries to install a package in their org before installing a dependency, a user-friendly message will be displayed asking to install the dependencies first.

Or, you can provide them with a script that would automatically install the dependencies and then the actual package. Sample script is present [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_sample_script.htm).

---

***Update:***

You can have any # of package directories in a single SFDX project (*although, only one package directory can be set as default*) and have them defined in the *sfdx-project.json* file. In the screenshot below, you can see that there are 2 package directories `force-app` & `customer-app`. One will be used for the source code of your core package, while the other for the customer related package. Note that the SFDX source folders and structure under each of this package directories will be the same. In the `sfdx-project.json` file, you can see that I've defined the both of these package directories, while having customer package as dependent on core package via `dependencies`. You can define any # of dependencies for a single package.

[image]

Within a single SFDX project, you can use `force:package` CLI commands to generate package for each of the package directories individually. You might want to check out [2GP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) & [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm). This [github project](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces) is a good reference for seeing how multiple package directories with dependencies can be placed within a single SFDX project.

Comment: Thanks @arut for the explanation. We are not going to include the core managed package inside the customer related package when build the customer related package. What we are trying to achieve is to have two separate folder for core and customer source in a Sfdx project and try to build one package. Will this possible?

Comment: That is exactly what I intended to be done via dependent packaging. Check out the updated answer. Hope that gives a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @arut. This is the exact explanation I wanted to know.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we can have any # of package directories in a single SFDX project and can create different managed packages with the dependencies, and if a customer need to use the customer-app package do they need to install the core package as well or the customer-app package itself have the core package source?

Comment: Also, What about the namespaces for each packages? Can we have two different namespaces for those packages or can strict with one namespace called pak1 for both the packages?

Comment: (1) The package directories that you define & use within the SFDX project refers to the local directory only (_where metadata corresponding to a package is defined and used by `force:pacakge` commands_). So, you can use any # of package directories. (2) If a customer tries to install the customer app (_which had the dependency defined_), then a graceful message would be shown asking to install the dependencies first i.e., core package is not installed automatically **unless an explicit installation script is created**.

Comment: (3) During development, namespace is indicated in the `sfdx-project.json` file, while in app release process it is managed via **Namespace Registry**. So, during dev, you would use a single namespace. While I have specifically not tested dependencies with different namespaces in production, I believe it should be possible because a package (or dependent one) is uniquely identified by its name and version #. Namespace is a logical grouping of related packages. **SF recommends using a single namespace** and this will help you to be able to use `@namespaceAccessible` in future.

Comment: Both (2)  & (3) from my previous comments probably deserve a separate question to understand more in detail.